# bootstrap login form div from button - not staying open after clicking form

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the latest Bootstrap 3 and I have a button called "Login" which displays a form to login dropdown when clicked. So far, so good. Everything works. The only problem is that after clicking a form field, the entire form disappears ...due to the button dropdown closing. I read around that it's due to the 'e.StopPropagation' javascript but I added that part, I believe correctly, at the end of the HTML page but it still closes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     Login <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right toprightlogin" role="menu">
     <li>

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>



        </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
        <script>
     $(function() {
   // Setup drop down menu
   $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

   // Fix input element click problem
   $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
 });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the jquery & bootstrap.min.js file?

Comment: Yes, I have. The dropdown and everything else works fine, just the dropdown doesn't stay open when it's clicked. It closes.

Comment: try e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
$(function() {
    // Fix input element click problem
    $('.btn-group input').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Besides the different selector, `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` is not nessecary.

Comment: user2643870, you should accept this answer in case it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Bootstrap components so far, but what will happen if you replace *e.stopPropagation()* with *e.preventDefault()*.